# Weird std::string::size() in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, size, unsigned, unsigned-integer

The program will print "Entered the loop" if I use `input.size() - 1` as the for loop condition.

```
std::string input;
input = {""};
int i = 0;
for (; i < input.size() - 1; ++i)
{
    cout << "Entered the loop" << endl;
}
```

However, if I pass the value of `input.size() -1` to an integer (`checksize`):

```
std::string input;
input = {""};
int checksize = input.size() - 1;
int i = 0;
for (; i < checksize; ++i)
{
    cout << "Entered the loop" << endl;
}
```

then the program will not go into the loop and will not print "Entered the loop"

I was wondering why this happen? It seems the two pieces of code are the same to me.

Comment: No compiler warnings?

Comment: most compilers have signed-unsigned warning off by default, it generates a lot of false positives.   some compilers would warn about out-of-range assignment in 2nd example

Comment: And this is why numbers used for math should be signed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a victim of **unsigned** integers :)

`std::string::size()` returns an **unsigned integer** (of type equivalent to `size_t`).

When the compiler evaluates `input.size() - 1`, this kind of becomes `size_t(0) - 1`, and since the computation is done with **unsigned** integers, instead of -1 you get a very big integer number (MSVC 32-bit compiler prints `4294967295`, which corresponds to the maximum 32-bit unsigned integer value `2^32 - 1`).

So this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.size() - 1; ++i)
```

is kind of equivalent to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < /* very big positive number */; ++i)
```

which will print your message *many* times.

Instead, in the second case, when you evaluate `input.size() - 1` and then assign it to an `int` variable (which is `signed` by default), the compiler still computes `size_t(0) - 1` as a very big positive integer number, but then this number is converted to a (`signed`) `int`, resulting in `checksize` being initialized with `-1`, and your loop is never executed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checksize /* -1 */; ++i)
```

---

Considering this compilable code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string input;

#ifdef CASE1
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Entered the loop\n";
    }
#else
    cout << "input.size() - 1  == " << (input.size() - 1) << '\n';
    cout << "SIZE_MAX          == " << SIZE_MAX << '\n';

    int checkSize = input.size() - 1;
    cout << "checkSize == " << checkSize << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < checkSize; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Entered the loop\n";
    }
#endif
}
```

If you compile its `CASE1` with MSVC and `/W4` (**warning level 4**, which I *highly* suggest), you get a **warning** for your `for` loop condition:

> ```
> cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo /DCASE1 test.cpp
>
> test.cpp(10) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
> ```

which usually points to you that something is wrong with your code.

Instead, compiling without `CASE1`, gives no warnings and the following output (which shows that the `for` loop's body is never executed):

> ```
> cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo test.cpp
>
> input.size() - 1  == 4294967295
> SIZE_MAX          == 4294967295
> checkSize == -1
> ```

Comment: `input.size() - 1` is an unsigned computation, even if later assigned to int.  The compiler doesn't compute `0 - 1` as such; it converts 4294967295 to int . (which is not guaranteed to give the same result, but probably will)

Answer (score 2):

`input.size()` is an unsigned quantity. So when it is zero, subtracting 1 gives the maximum value for its type (a large positive integer, probably `SIZE_MAX`).

So the loop is entered because `0 < SIZE_MAX` is true.

But when you convert this large positive number to `int`, the number is out of range for `int`. So *implementation-defined* behaviour occurs, which probably produces `checksize == -1`. Then your loop is not entered because `0 < -1` is false.