# C++ is saying that -1 < 15 (in programming) is false

Tags: c++

I have a string called `in`, a string that has the value of *"Hello, World!"*. I also have an integer called `i` that has the value `-1`. When I ask C++ to print out if `i` is less than the length of `in` (`in.length()`), it says `false`, but when I try `-1 < 15`, it says true. Why does it say false?

I feel like this is extremely basic arithmetic.

Comment: You should read [Signed/unsigned comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5416414/555045)

Comment: Some related questions: [Weird std::string::size() in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090091/) -- [sizeof() operator in if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293749/) -- [Why does my program skip the while loop? 2 is bigger than -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57775122/) -- [c++ vector size. why -1 is greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250058/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`string::length()` returns an **unsigned** integer.  You can't compare that to a negative *signed* value, so the `-1` gets converted to an *unsigned* value, which wraps it to a very large number, which is not less than the string's length, hence the result is false.

`-1 < 15`, on the other hand, is comparing two *signed* integers, so no conversion is needed, and the result is true, as expected.

Comment: This is very interesting! I did not know of this. How can I make it so that it returns a signed integer?

Comment: "*How can I make it so that it returns a signed integer?*" - You can't change the **type** it returns. But you can *typecast* the **value** it returns, eg: `static_cast<int>(in.length())`

Comment: @Ceyhun that would require a language change proposal. And it would be unlikely to pass the committee. You can however cast the return value to a signed number.

Comment: That was what I was asking for - Thank you! I will accept this answer when I can.

Comment: @Ceyhun You can use `std::ssize(in)` to get the "signed size". Or you can use [`std::cmp_less(-1, in.size())`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp) to do the comparison without conversion to unsigned. But you really should just turn on your compiler warning for signed/unsigned comparison.